# Robots.txt allow directory root while disallowing all deeper URLs

Tags: web-crawlers, robots.txt, regex

I would like to allow a path and disallow everything else in the directory.

```
User-Agent: *
Allow: /example/
Disallow: /example/*
```

Will this work? If not what would be a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

I actually found this helpful.

https://moz.com/community/q/robots-txt-how-to-exclude-sub-directories-correctly

```
User-Agent: *
allow: /example/$
disallow: /example/*
```

Comment: The "$" matches the end of a URL for anyone curious. More info: https://developers.google.com/search/reference/robots_txt

Comment: Worth pointing out that the rule set only works with user agents that support both the `Allow` directive and regular expressions.   Googlebot will obey that properly, and probably Bingbot.  Not many other user agents will though.